# Compound interests: Months count.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> [image]

I know this is a geometric series question, but I just cannot keep track on the number of the months.  This is frustrating beyond words; the question above took me an hour (plus many lists and diagrams) to figure out all the compounding periods correctly.  Does any one have an algorithm?

Consider the first set of deposits.  At $t = 60$, the $59$ deposits become:

$$A_1 \ \ = \ \ 200 \sum_{k=1}^{\, 59} 1.005^k$$

Therefore, at the end of $1999$, which is the end of the $180$-th period, we have:
$$A_1 \ \ = \ \ 1.005^{121} \cdot 200 \sum_{k=1}^{\, 59} 1.005^k \ \ = \ \ 1.005^{122} \cdot 200 \cdot \frac{1-1.005^{59}}{1-1.005}$$

The second set of deposits take place between $t = 73$ and $t = 180$ inclusive.  Thus:
$$A_2 \ \ = \ \ 200 \sum_{k=1}^{\, 108} 1.005^k \ \ = \ \ 200 \cdot 1.005 \cdot \frac{1-1.005^{108}}{1-1.005}$$

If you add up $A_1$ and $A_2$, the total value is $53839.83$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $k$-th deposit has compounded interest for $n+1-k=181-k$ periods. Thus we are missing the powers of $1.005$ from $181-72=109$ to $181-60=121$. Denote $1.005$ by $a$ and we then consider
$$
a+a^2+...+a^{108}+a^{122}+...+a^{180}
$$
which can then be written as
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{180}a^k-\sum_{k=1}^{121}a^k+\sum_{k=1}^{108}a^k
&=\frac{a^{181}-a}{a-1}-\frac{a^{122}-a}{a-1}+\frac{a^{109}-a}{a-1}\\
&=\frac{a^{181}-a^{122}+a^{109}-a}{a-1}
\end{align}
$$
so the answer will be
$$
200\cdot\frac{1.005^{181}-1.005^{122}+1.005^{109}-1.005}{0.005}=53839.8336...
$$
You can see how this could be turned into a much more general algorithm for missed payments.

Comment: Thanks.  What I meant is that I have problems figuring out how many compounding periods the $k$-th deposit should have.  A lot a times I had to resort to counting fingers (no kidding) or writing $k \mapsto n + 1 - k$.  I still can't do this kind of stuff inside my head.

Comment: @AndyTam: I know! Off-by-one-errors are the most common mistakes. Also they are a part of the constant fight between mathematicians and computer scientists ;)